# Why does glGetUniformBlockIndex() return INVALID_INDEX?

Tags: opengl, vertex-shader, uniform

I’m using the following vertex shader in a program, but for some reason, `glGetUniformBlockIndex(id, "draw2DQuadVS")` returns `INVALID_INDEX`.

The program is linked correctly before being used and the correct id is passed. Furthermore, no opengl error is set. Any explanation?

```
    #version 410
    uniform CBPostProcessVS
    {
        vec4  f4_Proj2DTo3D;
    } postProcessVS;

    uniform CBDraw2DQuadVS
    {
        vec4  f4_PositionOffsetAndScale;
        vec4  f4_TexcoordOffsetAndScale;
    } draw2DQuadVS;

        in vec3 vPosition;
    in vec2 vTexcoord0;
    in vec4 vColor0;
    in vec3 vTangent;
    in vec3 vBinormal;
    in vec3 vNormal;


    out vec2 v_vTexcoord0;
    out vec3 vPosFactor;


    void main()
    {    
        vec2 pos = (vec2(vPosition) * draw2DQuadVS.f4_PositionOffsetAndScale.zw) + vec2(draw2DQuadVS.f4_PositionOffsetAndScale);
        vec2 uv = (vec2(vTexcoord0) * draw2DQuadVS.f4_TexcoordOffsetAndScale.zw) + vec2(draw2DQuadVS.f4_TexcoordOffsetAndScale);

        gl_Position = vec4(pos,0,1);
        v_vTexcoord0 = uv;

        vPosFactor.xy = uv * vec2(postProcessVS.f4_Proj2DTo3D) + postProcessVS.f4_Proj2DTo3D.zw;
        vPosFactor.z = 1.0;
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

```
glGetUniformBlockIndex(id, "draw2DQuadVS")
```

`draw2DQuadsVS` is *not* the name of the uniform block. The name of the block is `CBDraw2DQuadVS`. `draw2DQuadsVS` is just the GLSL name of the block's scope.

More information can be found on the [OpenGL Wiki page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Interface_Block_%28GLSL%29#Syntax).